# How, from an array of objects, does one group, merge and aggregate values, each task by one or more different property-names / object-keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge, grouping

I have an array of objects as below.

I would like to group those with the same `bank`, `gender`, `age`, and `state` together.

I'd like to **sum** their `depositAmount` and `withdrawalAmount` together, respectively, and **count** each group as well. (`user` is excluded in the output)

**Example Array**

```
[{
    "bank": "bank1",
    "user": "u1",
    "depositAmount": 12,
    "withdrawalAmount": 33,
    "gender": "male",
    "age": 38,
    "state": "Arizona"
},
{
    "bank": "bank1",
    "user": "u2",
    "depositAmount": 25,
    "withdrawalAmount": 44,
    "gender": "male",
    "age": 38,
    "state": "Arizona"
},
{
    "bank": "bank2",
    "user": "u3",
    "depositAmount": 10,
    "withdrawalAmount": 0,
    "gender": "male",
    "age": 38,
    "state": "Florida"
}]
```

**Expected Output**

```
[{  
    "bank": "bank1"
    "depositAmount": 27,
    "withdrawalAmount": 77,
    "gender": "male",
    "age": 38,
    "state": "Arizona"
    "count": 2
},
{  
    "bank": "bank2"
    "depositAmount": 10,
    "withdrawalAmount": 0,
    "gender": "male",
    "age": 38,
    "state": "Florida"
    "count": 1
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generic solution to this problem was to implement a configurable reducer-function for the ... ***"It groups, merges and aggregates"*** task.

In order to cover the OP's requirements, one provides an accordingly tailored custom collector-object as the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)-method's [initial value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#how_reduce_works_with_an_initial_value).

The generic reducer expects to get provided a `createKey`, a `createMerger` and an `aggregate` function as well as a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) based `lookup` and an empty `result`-array where the latter, once the reduce task has been run, will hold all the grouped/merged and aggregated objects.

As for the OP's specific requirements the provided functions are ...

- OP ...

  > *"I would like to group those with the same `bank`, `gender`, `age`, and `state` together."*

  - `createKey: ({ bank, gender, age, state }) => [bank, gender, age, state].join('_')`
- OP ...

  > *"I'd like to **sum** their `depositAmount` and `withdrawalAmount` together, respectively, and **count** each group as well. (`user` is excluded in the output)."*

  - `createMerger: ({ bank, gender, age, state }) => ({ bank, gender, age, state, count: 0, depositAmount: 0, withdrawalAmount: 0 })`
  - `aggregate: (merger, { depositAmount, withdrawalAmount }) => { ++merger.count; merger.depositAmount += depositAmount; merger.withdrawalAmount += withdrawalAmount; }`

```js
function groupMergeAndAggregateGenerically(collector, item) {
  const {
    createKey, createMerger, aggregate,
    lookup, result = [],
  } = collector;

  const key = createKey(item);
  let merger = lookup.get(key) ?? null;

  if (merger === null) {
    merger = createMerger(item);

    lookup.set(key, merger);
    result.push(merger);
  }
  aggregate(merger, item);

  return collector;
}

const sampleData = [{
  "bank": "bank1",
  "user": "u1",
  "depositAmount": 12,
  "withdrawalAmount": 33,
  "gender": "male",
  "age": 38,
  "state": "Arizona"
}, {
  "bank": "bank1",
  "user": "u2",
  "depositAmount": 25,
  "withdrawalAmount": 44,
  "gender": "male",
  "age": 38,
  "state": "Arizona"
}, {
  "bank": "bank2",
  "user": "u3",
  "depositAmount": 10,
  "withdrawalAmount": 0,
  "gender": "male",
  "age": 38,
  "state": "Florida"
}];

// OP: I would like to group those with the same
// `bank`, `gender`, `age`, and `state` together.
const createKey = ({ bank, gender, age, state }) =>
  [bank, gender, age, state].join('_');

// OP: I'd like to sum their `depositAmount` and
// `withdrawalAmount` together, respectively, and
// `count` each group as well. (`user` is excluded in the output).
const createMerger = ({ bank, gender, age, state }) => ({
  bank, gender, age, state, count: 0, depositAmount: 0, withdrawalAmount: 0,
});
const aggregate = (merger, { depositAmount, withdrawalAmount }) => {
  ++merger.count;
  merger.depositAmount += depositAmount;
  merger.withdrawalAmount += withdrawalAmount;
};

const { result: mergedData } = sampleData
  .reduce(groupMergeAndAggregateGenerically, {
    createKey,
    createMerger,
    aggregate,
    lookup: new Map,
    result: [],      
  });

console.log({ mergedData });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```