# How to group and merge array entries and to sum-up values on multiple common (but not all) keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, merge, grouping

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444738/sum-similar-keys-in-an-array-of-objects/57477448#57477448) had multiple approaches for summing values by common key, and one had a method to group by all common keys. I am looking for a more granular and controlled grouping. My data example is the following:

```
const arr = [
{'ID':'1','Parent':'1','Member': '1','Code': '123','Subject': 'Org A','value': 0.3},
{'ID':'2','Parent':'1','Member': '1','Code': '124','Subject': 'Org A','value': 0.25},
{'ID':'3','Parent':'1','Member': '1','Code': '123','Subject': 'Org B','value': 0.45},
{'ID':'4','Parent':'1','Member': '2','Code': '125','Subject': 'Org A','value': 0.8},
{'ID':'5','Parent':'1','Member': '2','Code': '211','Subject': 'Org C','value': 0.3},
{'ID':'6','Parent':'1','Member': '3','Code': '221','Subject': 'Org B','value': 0.3},
{'ID':'7','Parent':'1','Member': '3','Code': '221','Subject': 'Org C','value': 0.25},
{'ID':'8','Parent':'1','Member': '3','Code': '234','Subject': 'Org A','value': 0.45},
{'ID':'9','Parent':'1','Member': '4','Code': '123','Subject': 'Org A','value': 0.8},
{'ID':'10','Parent':'2','Member': '5','Code': '123','Subject': 'Org D','value': 0.3},
{'ID':'11','Parent':'2','Member': '5','Code': '123','Subject': 'Org E','value': 0.3},
{'ID':'12','Parent':'2','Member': '6','Code': '125','Subject': 'Org E','value': 0.25},
{'ID':'13','Parent':'2','Member': '6','Code': '211','Subject': 'Org F','value': 0.45},
{'ID':'14','Parent':'2','Member': '6','Code': '221','Subject': 'Org F','value': 0.8},
{'ID':'15','Parent':'2','Member': '6','Code': '123','Subject': 'Org G','value': 0.3},
{'ID':'16','Parent':'3','Member': '7','Code': '124','Subject': 'Org H','value': 0.3},
{'ID':'17','Parent':'3','Member': '8','Code': '124','Subject': 'Org H','value': 0.25},
{'ID':'18','Parent':'3','Member': '9','Code': '123','Subject': 'Org I','value': 0.45},
{'ID':'19','Parent':'3','Member': '10','Code': '123','Subject': 'Org J','value': 0.8},
{'ID':'20','Parent':'3','Member': '10','Code': '211','Subject': 'Org I','value': 0.3},
{'ID':'21','Parent':'4','Member': '11','Code': '221','Subject': 'Org K','value': 0.3},
{'ID':'22','Parent':'4','Member': '11','Code': '234','Subject': 'Org K','value': 0.25},
{'ID':'23','Parent':'4','Member': '12','Code': '234','Subject': 'Org K','value': 0.45},
{'ID':'24','Parent':'4','Member': '12','Code': '123','Subject': 'Org L','value': 0.8},
{'ID':'25','Parent':'4','Member': '13','Code': '211','Subject': 'Org M','value': 0.3}
];
```

The solutions from the other thread either group by 1 set column:

```
// Group by 1 column //

const summed = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const item = acc.length > 0 && acc.find(({
    Code
  }) => Code === cur.Code)
  if (item) {
    item.value += cur.value
  } else acc.push({Code:cur.Code,value:cur.value});
  return acc
}, [])
console.log(arr); // not modified
console.log(summed)
```

Or by all common values

```
// Group by multiple columns //

const res = Array.from(arr.reduce((acc, {value, ...r}) => {
  const key = JSON.stringify(r);
  const current = acc.get(key) || {...r, value: 0};  
  return acc.set(key, {...current, value: current.value + value});
}, new Map).values());
console.log(res);
```

I am trying to group by Parent and Code to sum the value.

Comment: Use the first solution, just test both keys in the `find()` call.

Comment: `find(({Parent, Code}) => Code == cur.Code && Parent == cur.Parent)`

Comment: The OP might find an answer in the entirely generic implemented approach posted as a solution to this recently asked question ... [_"How, from an array of objects, does one group, merge and aggregate values, each task by one or more different property-names / object-keys?"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72404195/how-from-an-array-of-objects-does-one-group-merge-and-aggregate-values-each/72405803#72405803)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just test both properties in the `find()` callback, and add both to the new object when pushing into `acc`.

```js
const arr = [
{'ID':'1','Parent':'1','Member': '1','Code': '123','Subject': 'Org A','value': 0.3},
{'ID':'2','Parent':'1','Member': '1','Code': '124','Subject': 'Org A','value': 0.25},
{'ID':'3','Parent':'1','Member': '1','Code': '123','Subject': 'Org B','value': 0.45},
{'ID':'4','Parent':'1','Member': '2','Code': '125','Subject': 'Org A','value': 0.8},
{'ID':'5','Parent':'1','Member': '2','Code': '211','Subject': 'Org C','value': 0.3},
{'ID':'6','Parent':'1','Member': '3','Code': '221','Subject': 'Org B','value': 0.3},
{'ID':'7','Parent':'1','Member': '3','Code': '221','Subject': 'Org C','value': 0.25},
{'ID':'8','Parent':'1','Member': '3','Code': '234','Subject': 'Org A','value': 0.45},
{'ID':'9','Parent':'1','Member': '4','Code': '123','Subject': 'Org A','value': 0.8},
{'ID':'10','Parent':'2','Member': '5','Code': '123','Subject': 'Org D','value': 0.3},
{'ID':'11','Parent':'2','Member': '5','Code': '123','Subject': 'Org E','value': 0.3},
{'ID':'12','Parent':'2','Member': '6','Code': '125','Subject': 'Org E','value': 0.25},
{'ID':'13','Parent':'2','Member': '6','Code': '211','Subject': 'Org F','value': 0.45},
{'ID':'14','Parent':'2','Member': '6','Code': '221','Subject': 'Org F','value': 0.8},
{'ID':'15','Parent':'2','Member': '6','Code': '123','Subject': 'Org G','value': 0.3},
{'ID':'16','Parent':'3','Member': '7','Code': '124','Subject': 'Org H','value': 0.3},
{'ID':'17','Parent':'3','Member': '8','Code': '124','Subject': 'Org H','value': 0.25},
{'ID':'18','Parent':'3','Member': '9','Code': '123','Subject': 'Org I','value': 0.45},
{'ID':'19','Parent':'3','Member': '10','Code': '123','Subject': 'Org J','value': 0.8},
{'ID':'20','Parent':'3','Member': '10','Code': '211','Subject': 'Org I','value': 0.3},
{'ID':'21','Parent':'4','Member': '11','Code': '221','Subject': 'Org K','value': 0.3},
{'ID':'22','Parent':'4','Member': '11','Code': '234','Subject': 'Org K','value': 0.25},
{'ID':'23','Parent':'4','Member': '12','Code': '234','Subject': 'Org K','value': 0.45},
{'ID':'24','Parent':'4','Member': '12','Code': '123','Subject': 'Org L','value': 0.8},
{'ID':'25','Parent':'4','Member': '13','Code': '211','Subject': 'Org M','value': 0.3}
];

const summed = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const item = acc.length > 0 && acc.find(({
    Code, Parent
  }) => Code === cur.Code && Parent == cur.Parent)
  if (item) {
    item.value += cur.value
  } else acc.push({
    Code: cur.Code,
    Parent: cur.Parent,
    value: cur.value
  });
  return acc
}, [])
console.log(arr); // not modified
console.log(summed)
```

Answer (score 0):

From my above comment ...

> *The OP might find an answer in the entirely generic implemented approach posted as a solution to this recently asked question ... ["How, from an array of objects, does one group, merge and aggregate values, each task by one or more different property-names / object-keys?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72404195/how-from-an-array-of-objects-does-one-group-merge-and-aggregate-values-each/72405803#72405803)*

```js
function groupMergeAndAggregateGenerically(collector, item) {
  const {
    createKey, createMerger, aggregate,
    lookup, result = [],
  } = collector;

  const key = createKey(item);
  let merger = lookup.get(key) ?? null;

  if (merger === null) {
    merger = createMerger(item);

    lookup.set(key, merger);
    result.push(merger);
  }
  aggregate(merger, item);

  return collector;
}

const arr = [
  { 'ID':'1','Parent':'1','Member': '1','Code': '123','Subject': 'Org A','value': 0.3 },
  { 'ID':'2','Parent':'1','Member': '1','Code': '124','Subject': 'Org A','value': 0.25 },
  { 'ID':'3','Parent':'1','Member': '1','Code': '123','Subject': 'Org B','value': 0.45 },
  { 'ID':'4','Parent':'1','Member': '2','Code': '125','Subject': 'Org A','value': 0.8 },
  { 'ID':'5','Parent':'1','Member': '2','Code': '211','Subject': 'Org C','value': 0.3 },
  { 'ID':'6','Parent':'1','Member': '3','Code': '221','Subject': 'Org B','value': 0.3 },
  { 'ID':'7','Parent':'1','Member': '3','Code': '221','Subject': 'Org C','value': 0.25 },
  { 'ID':'8','Parent':'1','Member': '3','Code': '234','Subject': 'Org A','value': 0.45 },
  { 'ID':'9','Parent':'1','Member': '4','Code': '123','Subject': 'Org A','value': 0.8 },
  { 'ID':'10','Parent':'2','Member': '5','Code': '123','Subject': 'Org D','value': 0.3 },
  { 'ID':'11','Parent':'2','Member': '5','Code': '123','Subject': 'Org E','value': 0.3 },
  { 'ID':'12','Parent':'2','Member': '6','Code': '125','Subject': 'Org E','value': 0.25 },
  { 'ID':'13','Parent':'2','Member': '6','Code': '211','Subject': 'Org F','value': 0.45 },
  { 'ID':'14','Parent':'2','Member': '6','Code': '221','Subject': 'Org F','value': 0.8 },
  { 'ID':'15','Parent':'2','Member': '6','Code': '123','Subject': 'Org G','value': 0.3 },
  { 'ID':'16','Parent':'3','Member': '7','Code': '124','Subject': 'Org H','value': 0.3 },
  { 'ID':'17','Parent':'3','Member': '8','Code': '124','Subject': 'Org H','value': 0.25 },
  { 'ID':'18','Parent':'3','Member': '9','Code': '123','Subject': 'Org I','value': 0.45 },
  { 'ID':'19','Parent':'3','Member': '10','Code': '123','Subject': 'Org J','value': 0.8 },
  { 'ID':'20','Parent':'3','Member': '10','Code': '211','Subject': 'Org I','value': 0.3 },
  { 'ID':'21','Parent':'4','Member': '11','Code': '221','Subject': 'Org K','value': 0.3 },
  { 'ID':'22','Parent':'4','Member': '11','Code': '234','Subject': 'Org K','value': 0.25 },
  { 'ID':'23','Parent':'4','Member': '12','Code': '234','Subject': 'Org K','value': 0.45 },
  { 'ID':'24','Parent':'4','Member': '12','Code': '123','Subject': 'Org L','value': 0.8 },
  { 'ID':'25','Parent':'4','Member': '13','Code': '211','Subject': 'Org M','value': 0.3 },
];

const { result: mergedData } = arr
  .reduce(groupMergeAndAggregateGenerically, {
    // OP: "I am trying to group by Parent and Code ..."
    createKey: ({ Parent, Code }) => [Parent, Code].join('_'),
    createMerger: ({ Parent, Code }) => ({ Parent, Code, value: 0 }),
    // OP: "[and] ... to sum the value."
    aggregate: (merger, { value }) => merger.value += value,
    lookup: new Map,
    result: [],      
  });

console.log({ mergedData });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```