# how to return new array by using array.reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, find, lookup, reduce

I want to return new array by using reduce. For example,

```
const product = [
  { color: 'orange', type: 'hat', count: 1 },
  { color: 'orange', type: 'hat', count: 1 },
  { color: 'orange', type: 'shoes', count: 1 },
  { color: 'blue', type: 'food', count: 1 },
];
```

the product list need to like below because there are two 'hat' therefore, the count should be 2 and one { color: 'orange', type: 'hat', count: 1 } should be removed.

```
const result = product.reduce((acc, curr) => {
// I want to make new array like
// const product = [
//  { color: 'orange', type: 'hat', count: 2 },
//  { color: 'orange', type: 'shoes', count: 1 },
//  { color: 'blue', type: 'food', count: 1 },
//];
 return acc
}
```

thank you!

Comment: The task also could be described as _**grouping, merging and aggregating**_. It is a quite common task and can be solved by a generically implemented but customizable reducer function ... see ... [_"How to group and merge array entries and to sum-up values on multiple common (but not all) keys?"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72411474/how-to-group-and-merge-array-entries-and-to-sum-up-values-on-multiple-common-bu)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72411474/how-to-group-and-merge-array-entries-and-to-sum-up-values-on-multiple-common-bu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it the following way :

- First find if the product has already been added to the `curr` array
- If yes, increments the `count`
- else, push the new product into the array

*Note* : I've used the [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to make a deep copy of the object instead of pushing the current object into the array.

This result by not modifying the `products` array and create a completely new array

```js
const product = [
  { color: 'orange', type: 'hat', count: 1 },
  { color: 'orange', type: 'hat', count: 1 },
  { color: 'orange', type: 'shoes', count: 1 },
  { color: 'blue', type: 'food', count: 1 },
];

const result = product.reduce((acc, curr) => {
 if(!acc) return [...curr]
 
 const exist = acc.find(x => x.type === curr.type && x.color === curr.color)
 exist ? exist.count += 1 : acc.push({...curr})
 return acc
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it

```js
const product = [
  { color: 'orange', type: 'hat', count: 1 },
  { color: 'orange', type: 'hat', count: 1 },
  { color: 'orange', type: 'shoes', count: 1 },
  { color: 'blue', type: 'food', count: 1 },
];

const result = product.reduce((res, obj) => {
  let exist = res.find(o => o.color === obj.color && o.type === obj.type)
  if (exist) {
    exist.count += obj.count
  } else {
    res = [...res, {...obj}]
  }
  return [...res]
}, [])
console.log(result)
console.log(product)
```

**Update** Edit with suggestion by [yassine-el-bouchaibi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19294469/yassine-el-bouchaibi)

Comment: This answer is dangerous as you are modifying `count` on the original object. This could create unintended behaviour if OP wants to re-use the objects in products afterwards as they wouldn’t know some inner objects were muted. That is a bad practice. Better to make a copy instead of re-attributing `count` on exist.

Answer (score 0):

From the above comment ...

> *The task also could be described as ***grouping, merging and aggregating***. It is a quite common task and can be solved by a generically implemented but customizable reducer function ... see ... [*"How to group and merge array entries and to sum-up values on multiple common (but not all) keys?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72411474/how-to-group-and-merge-array-entries-and-to-sum-up-values-on-multiple-common-bu)*

... prove ...

```js
function groupMergeAndAggregateGenerically(collector, item) {
  const {
    createKey, createMerger, aggregate,
    lookup, result = [],
  } = collector;

  const key = createKey(item);
  let merger = lookup.get(key) ?? null;

  if (merger === null) {
    merger = createMerger(item);

    lookup.set(key, merger);
    result.push(merger);
  }
  aggregate(merger, item);

  return collector;
}

const productData = [
  { color: 'orange', type: 'hat', count: 1 },
  { color: 'orange', type: 'hat', count: 1 },
  { color: 'orange', type: 'shoes', count: 1 },
  { color: 'blue', type: 'food', count: 1 },
];
const { result: mergedData } = productData
  .reduce(groupMergeAndAggregateGenerically, {
    createKey: ({ color, type }) => [color, type].join('_'),
    createMerger: ({ color, type }) => ({ color, type, count: 0 }),
    aggregate: (merger, { count }) => merger.count += count,
    lookup: new Map,
    result: [],      
  });

console.log({ mergedData, productData });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```