# Accumulated values into new keyed object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

My data:

```js
const data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "location": 30,
    "year": 2019
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "location": 15,
    "year": 2000
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "location": 25,
    "year": 2019
  }
];
```

My desired outcome:

```js
accumluatedData = [{
    "id": [1],
    "year": 2019,
    "frequency": 2
  },
  {
    "id": [2],
    "year": 2000,
    "frequency": 1
  }
];
```

What I have so far (with the kind help of other stackoverflowers), is getting into an array (see code below).

However, I would like to get it into an object (as shown above).

Any suggestions? Am I on the right track? Or should I use a different route?

```js
const data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "location": 30,
    "year": 2019
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "location": 15,
    "year": 2000
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "location": 25,
    "year": 2019
  }
];


var results = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  if (results[data[i].year]) {
    results[data[i].year]++;
  } else {
    results[data[i].year] = 1;
  }
};

console.log("results", results);
```

Comment: use an object where key is the id and do the for loop thing you did. finally get Object.values of the object

Comment: Will the "id" for a given year always be the same?  For example would you ever have an entry in 2019 with an id other than 1?   If so, what ID should `accumulatedData` contain for that year?

Comment: use `var results = {};` instead of `var results = [];`

Comment: Thanks Daniel, no the ID varies, so there are entries of 2019 with 2 or 3.

Comment: Does this help with answering the Q ?.. [_"How, from an array of objects, does one group, merge and aggregate values, each task by one or more different property-names / object-keys?"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72404195/how-from-an-array-of-objects-does-one-group-merge-and-aggregate-values-each/72405803#72405803)

Comment: "the ID varies, so there are entries of 2019 with 2 or 3" in that case your output data format  needs to be changed, because there's no way to know which ID to include on a given entry.

Comment: anyway you can group by the combination of year+id. for example the results object can have keys like "2019|1" or "2020|3" like that

Comment: Thanks @DanielBeck, good point! The IDs can therefore be in an array; adding IDs as they occur. I've edited the desired outcome.