# Merge 2 arrays of object based on specific object key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have 2 arrays which is contains same id with different value (inside selected)
My goal is to merge both become 1 array.

When I use spread operator like this:

```
data = [
  ...data.filter(
    (a) => a.id === newData.id
  ),
  newData];
```

It comes the data being override

First array

```
[
 {
    id: "A527CFFE",
    selected: [
      {
        itemId: "A1",
        text: "Selected 1"
      }
    ]
 }
]
```

Second array

```
[
 {
    id: "A527CFFE",
    selected: [
      {
        itemId: "A2",
        text: "Selected 2"
      }
    ]
 }
]
```

How can I make both of arrays become 1 ? the expected result:

```
[
 {
    id: "A527CFFE",
    selected: [
      {
        itemId: "A1",
        text: "Selected 1"
      },
      {
        itemId: "A2",
        text: "Selected 1"
      }
    ]
 }
]
```

What am I doing wrong in the above?

Comment: Do both arrays always have same items (same `id`s)?

Comment: Hi @ulou yes it always have a same id

Comment: For similar (even more complex) tasks of the ever same underlying problem/pattern of _"grouping, merging and aggregating"_ one, for the latter, might consider [a generic approach in combination with custom provided functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72404195/how-from-an-array-of-objects-does-one-group-merge-and-aggregate-values-each/72405803#72405803) for each ... _group, merge and aggregate_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to combine the two arrays into one.

We start by concatenating and then grouping by id. For each item with the same ids we combine the `selected` arrays.

```js
const arr1 = [ { id: "A527CFFE", selected: [ { itemId: "A1", text: "Selected 1" } ] } ]
const arr2 = [ { id: "A527CFFE", selected: [ { itemId: "A2", text: "Selected 2" } ] } ]

const result = Object.values([...arr1, ...arr2].reduce((acc, { id, selected }) => { 
    acc[id] = acc[id] || { id, selected: [] };
    acc[id].selected = [...acc[id].selected, ...selected];
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log('Result:', result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: A better-written answer and better code.

Comment: Thanks !, this is what I need, I managed to use this with some modification and my issue has been resolved. Again many thanks !

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arrA=[{id:"A527CFFE",selected:[{itemId:"A1",text:"Selected 1"}]}]
const arrB=[{id:"A527CFFE",selected:[{itemId:"A2",text:"Selected 2"}]}]

const res = arrA.map(e => { // map all items of first array
  const found = arrB.find(x => x.id === e.id) // find item in second array with same id
  return found // check if item has been found in second array
      ? {id: e.id, selected: [...e.selected, ...found.selected]} // if yes, merged selected 
      : e // if no, return only item from first array         
})

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; } /* ignore this */
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I managed to fix the problem using part of your code :)